# How to display gridview in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

The following code is used to display gridview but it shows "data provider" error.

MODELS:

Subcategory.php:

```
public function getCountries()
 {
     return $this->hasOne(Subcategories::className(),['id'=>'catid']);
 }
```

VIEW:

subcategory.php:
 i have added this following coding to view the saved data in a grid view.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns'=>[
    ['class'=>'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    'categoryname',
    [
        'attribute' => subcategory,
        'value'=>getCountries.subcatname,
    ],
    ['class'=>'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
]); ?>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function actionView2()
{
  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => Subcategory::find(),
      'pagination' => [
          'pageSize' => 20
       ]
   ]);
   $posts = $dataProvider->getModels();
   return $this->render('subcategory' [
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]);
}
```

I have applied this coding but I get the following error:

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Undefined variable: dataProvider
```

Comment: show respective controller code also.

Comment: edit your post to add details.

Comment: Post the controller code

Comment: check if you pass the correct variable to correct render file

Comment: The `View` code has errors, You've not quoted `subcategory` and `getCountries.subcatname`

Comment: i beg ur pardon...pls help me in fixing this issue. above code is the one which i tried i don hav any other code.pls can u give me some code